# Share a file with specific user/s and allow them to access it for one time only

Tags: azure, office365, sharepoint-online, azure-information-protection

I received a requirement to allow sharing a file with specific external user/s and allow them to access it for one time only.. so can we achieve this ?

Comment: Thinking about this a little, once they have the file, obviously they can do whatever they want with it, so basically you are aiming to avoid them seeing future modifications to the file?  If so, perhaps a low tech solution is to copy the current state of the file, and give the external users access to the copy (which will never be updated)?

Comment: @AndrewMcClement we are already preventing external users for downloading the files,, so they have to view it online and we want to force this to happen for one time only